# How to get spring bean properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-actuator

I'm loading all loaded beans that have @Configuration annotation like

```
Map<String, Object> beans = context.getBeansWithAnnotation(Configuration.class)
```

It return a map of <bean-name, Object>

on each configuration, the bean-configuration will have properties

I want to map all bean's properties to a map of property-name, property-value <String, Object>

I can see those on IDE's debugger tools but don't know how to convert them into a map

[image]
Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance

Comment: if you could share a screenshot of what IDEs are saying you? if you mean the fields of java object, then you could use reflection to get list of those and their values..

Comment: I added in post details. But I am expecting to convert all properties to a map <key, value> of all configurations, not only specific instance

Comment: I am confused. this actuator endpoint returns Spring's "configuration properties",  it has nothing to do with the bean properties of configuration beans in Java speak. a "configuration" is just a singleton, a "configuration properties" in Spring is another singleton (as least, normally). multiple "configuration"-s might depend on single "configuration properties" instance, and vice versa.

Comment: can you create a sample project and manually write what you would want to see in this map, for that project? like "foo=bar" etc